# On table row click hide or show other table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

In this html

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AllCommonMatches.Length; i++)
{
    <tr class="category">
        <td>@Model.AllCommonMatches[i].StartDateTime.ToString("dddd dd MMMM HH:mm")</td>          
        <td>@Model.AllCommonMatches[i].EndDateTime.ToString("dddd dd MMMM HH:mm")</td>
        <td>@Model.AllCommonMatches[i].AvailableAttendees.Count &nbsp; of &nbsp; @Model.TotalAttendees</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subcategory">
       @foreach (var person in Model.AllCommonMatches[i].AvailableAttendees)
       {
           <td>@person.Email &nbsp; &nbsp; @person.FirstName &nbsp;&nbsp;@person.LastName</td>
       }
    </tr>                     
}
```

Is it possible to have on tr with category click show/hide tr with subcategory?
I don't have much knowledge about the front end part.

Comment: if subcategory is always 1 next to its category,
a jquery solution is
$('.category').on('click',function(){
$(this).hide().next().hide();
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a little JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/veritas87/QSw3w/

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('tr.category').on('click', function() { 
       $(this).next('.subcategory').fadeToggle(); 
    });
});
```

In the JSFiddle you can find the CSS and HTML.

Comment: i tried tried this `<style>     subcategory {         display: none;     } </style>` to hide the td inside subcategory loads for first time but didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.toggle()` jQuery's method:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.category').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next('.subcategory').toggle(); // or .slideToggle() or whatever
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks! but if I had to hide all the subcategory by default then? what should I do?

Comment: Add a CSS rule: `.subcategory { display:none; }` I'll suggest you to read some basic tutos...

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it! Good answer +1

Comment: tried this `<style>
    subcategory {
        display: none;
    }
</style>` but didn't work :(

Comment: Ya, because it should be: `<style> .subcategory { display: none; } </style>` Really, please read some tutos!